# Replace tab with blank space

Tags: java, tabs

```
final String remove = "   " // tab is 3 spaces

while (lineOfText != null)
   {
       if (lineOfText.contains(remove))
       {
           lineOfText = " ";
        }
       outputFile.println(lineOfText);
       lineOfText = inputFile.readLine();
   }
```

I tried running this but it doesn't replace the tabs with one blank space. Any solutions?

Comment: Your `remove` variable is 3 spaces, that's not a tab. A tab would be something like `"\t"`. Also, the instruction `lineOfText = " ";` is replacing the whole string in `lineOfText` with a single space

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tab is not three spaces. It's a special character that you obtain with an escape, specifically `final String remove = "\t";` and

```
if (lineOfText.contains(remove))
    lineOfText = lineOfText.replaceAll(remove, " ");
}
```

or remove the `if` (because `replaceAll` doesn't need it) like,

```
lineOfText = lineOfText.replaceAll(remove, " ");
```

Comment: Use `replace()` if you're not using regex.

Comment: Thank you for this! Shmosel, what is regex?

Comment: @ChosenForWorlds Regex is regular expressions. It's a generic way to represent patterns of characters without specifically listing all actual character combinations.

Comment: @shmosel why should use replace() instead of replaceAll()

Comment: @velocity It's simpler and probably more efficient than a regex replacement.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use this regular expression to replace any type of escapes( including tabs, newlines, spaces etc.) within a String with the desired one:

```
lineOfText.replaceAll("\\s", " ");
```

Here in this example in the string named **lineOfText** we have replaced all escapes with whitespaces.

Comment: this would f.e. replace 3 consecutive whitespaces with 3 consecutive whitespaces, so lineOfText.replaceAll("\\s+", " "); would be more in the op's interest